# Difference of the square of the sum

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, array

**Find the difference between the square of the sums and sum of the squares.**

This is the mathematical representation:

\$\left(\sum n\right)^2-\sum n^2\$

Your program/method should take two inputs, these are your lower and upper limits of the range, and are inclusive.
Limits will be whole integers above 0.

Your program/method should return the answer.

You may use whichever base you would like to, but please state in your answer which base you have used.

Test case (Base 10)

```
5,9      970
91,123   12087152
1,10     2640
```

This is usual code-golf, so the shorter the answer the better.

Comment: It took me a while to realize the input was the endpoints of a range.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills edited for clarity

Comment: This is simpler than it looks ?

Comment: @cat what do you mean by that? Yes the maths is simple Alevel stuff. But it's all down to how you golf it

Comment: @george The question and many of the answers make it look like a lot of work, but it's [not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83601/46231)

Comment: @cat I never said it was a lot of work. As I mentioned above, it is simple Alevel mathematics.

Comment: I assume not, but may we take an array as input instead of the start and end points?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing amazing that people are still going at it a year and half later. When I wrote it I said two inputs, so in theory you could pass two arrays as input, but it must be two. Not one away with both inputs. Although I’d be interested to see both solutions

Answer (score 24):

## Python 2, 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b,s=0:b/a and 2*a*s+f(a+1,b,s+a)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1iCZ4l).

#### How it works

Call the function defined in the specification \$g(a, b)\$. We have that

$$
\newcommand{\sumab}[2]{\sum_{a \le #1 \le b} #2 \:}
\begin{align}
g(a,b) & = \left( \sumab n n \right)^2 - \sumab n {n^2} \\
& = \sumab {i,j} {ij} - \sumab n {n^2} \\
& = \sumab {i<j} {ij} + \sumab {i=j} {ij} + \sumab {j<i} {ij} - \sumab n {n^2} \\
& = 2 \sumab {j<i} {ij} \\
& = 2 \sumab {i} {\sum_{a \le i < j} ij} \\
& = \sumab {i} {\left( 2i \sum_{a \le j < i} j \right)}
\end{align}
$$

Define the function \$f(x, y, s)\$ recursively as follows.

$$ f(x, y, s) =
\begin{cases}
2xs + f(x+1, y, s+x) & \text{ if } x \le y \\
0 & \text{ if} x > y
\end{cases}
$$

By applying the recurrence relation of \$f(a, b, 0)\$ a total of \$b - a\$ times, we can show that:

$$
\begin{align}
f(a, b, 0) & = 2\cdot0 + f(a+1, b, a) \\
& = 2\cdot0 + 2\cdot(a+1)\cdot a + f(a+2, b, a+(a+1)) \\
& = 2\cdot0 + 2\cdot(a+1)\cdot a + 2\cdot(a+2)\cdot(a+(a+1)) + f(a+3, b, a+(a+1)+(a+2)) \\
& \vdots \\
& = \sumab {i} {\left( 2i \sum_{a \le j < i} j \right)} + f\left(b+1, b, \sumab j j\right) \\
& = \sumab {i} {\left( 2i \sum_{a \le j < i} j \right)} \\
& = g(a, b)
\end{align}
$$

This is the function **f** of the implementation. While `b/a` returns a non-zero integer, the code following `and` is executed, thus implementing the recursive definition of **f**.

Once `b/a` reaches **0**, we have that **b > a** and the lambda returns **False = 0**, thus implementing the base case of the definition of **f**.

Comment: ah okay. Could you explain your method though?

Comment: I will, but I'm currently trying to golf it a bit more.

Comment: thanks for the formula. I guess I never saw it like that because we don't cover sums of series like that at school. Pretty interesting though!

Comment: @george I've finished the explanation.

Comment: Wanna tell us a bit more of how in the world the idea to define f came into your mind! The motivation! I'm genuinely interested.

Answer (score 15):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
&:&*XRssE
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JjomKlhSc3NF&input=MQoxMA)

#### Explanation

```
&:   % Inclusive range between the two implicit inputs
&*   % Matrix of all pair-wise products
XR   % Upper triangular part of matrix, without the diagonal
ss   % Sum of all elements of the matrix
E    % Multiply by 2. Implicit display
```

#### Example

These are the partial results of each line for inputs `5` and `9`:

1. `&:`

   ```
   5 6 7 8 9
   ```
2. `&:&*`

   ```
   25 30 35 40 45
   30 36 42 48 54
   35 42 49 56 63
   40 48 56 64 72
   45 54 63 72 81
   ```
3. `&:&*XR`

   ```
   0 30 35 40 45
   0  0 42 48 54
   0  0  0 56 63
   0  0  0  0 72
   0  0  0  0  0
   ```
4. `&:&*XRss`

   ```
   485
   ```
5. `&:&*XRssE`

   ```
   970
   ```

Comment: I really like seeing the partial results. They really help with understanding the program. Thanks for including them!

Answer (score 10):

### Jelly, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
rµS²_²S$
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=csK1U8KyX8KyUyQ&input=&args=OTE+MTIz)

```
r         inclusive range from first input to second input
 µ        pass the range to a new monadic chain
  S       the sum
   ²      squared
    _     minus...
     ²S$  the squares summed
```

Thanks to [FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for a byte!

Comment: For once, Jelly is actually very readable.

Comment: Can I fork this to my answer?

Comment: @LeakyNun what does that mean?

Comment: [This](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83357/48934).

Comment: Nice earrings: S²_²S

Answer (score 10):

### Python 2, 45 bytes

```py
lambda a,b:(a+~b)*(a-b)*(3*(a+b)**2+a-b-2)/12
```

Closed form solution - not the shortest, but I thought it'd be worth posting anyway.

### Explanation

Let `p(n)` be the *n*th [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), and `t(n)` be the *n*th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Then, for *n* over the range *a*, ..., *b*:

- ∑n  = `t(b)-t(a-1)`, and
- ∑n² = `p(b) - p(a-1)`
- So (∑n)²-∑n² = `(t(b)-t(a-1))² - (p(b) - p(a-1))`.

This expression reduces to that in the code.

Comment: Hi could you explain your equation if possible. My python version is 16 bytes longer and I can't figure out how you derived your equation

Comment: @george Let `p(n)` be the `n`th [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), and `t(n)` be the `n`th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Then this is a simplified version of `(t(b)-t(a-1))^2 - (p(b) - p(a-1))`.

Comment: @MartinEnder So that is the exact formula that I have used, but Sp3000 has simplified it in a way that I cannot understand. My python script is: (b*-~b-a*~-a)**2/4-(b*-~b*(2*b+1)-a*~-a*(2*a-1))/6  if that is of any use. I have golfed as much as I can the two formula

Comment: @george Sometimes, with problems like these, the easiest way is to get [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorise+((b(b%2B1)-a(a-1))%5E2)%2F4+-+(b*(b%2B1)*(2b%2B1)-a*(a-1)*(2a-1))%2F6) to do the tedious part, then double checking to make sure it's right. To be honest, I don't think I could have pulled the `(a-b-1)` factor out of `(b*(b+1)*(2b+1)-a*(a-1)*(2a-1))/6` on my own.

Comment: @Sp3000 that's a great way to do it. I'll try that in future

Answer (score 6):

### 05AB1E, 8 bytes

```
ŸDOnsnO-
```

**Explained**

```
ŸD       # range from a to b, duplicate
  On     # sum and square first range
    s    # swap top 2 elements
     nO  # square and sum 2nd range
       - # take difference
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xbhET25zbk8t&input=OTEKMTIz)

Comment: Is 05AB1E a ROT13 version of Jelly maybe? Substitute r by Ÿ, µ by D, S by O, ² by n, _ by s and $ by -.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: They are quite different actually. A common offset between some "functions" are most likely a coincident. Jelly is a tacit language about chaining functions (afaik), while 05AB1E is a stack based language.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Tr[x=Range@##]^2-x.x&
```

An unnamed function taking two arguments and returning the difference. Usage:

```
Tr[x=Range@##]^2-x.x&[91, 123]
(* 12087152 *)
```

There's three small (and fairly standard) golfing tricks here:

- `##` represents both arguments at once, so that we can use prefix notation for `Range`. `Range@##` is shorthand for `Range[##]` which expands to `Range[a, b]` and gives us an inclusive range as required.
- `Tr` is for *trace* but using it on a vector simply sums that vector, saving three bytes over `Total`.
- `x.x` is a dot product, saving four bytes over `Tr[x^2]`.

Comment: Would `Variance` help?

Comment: @LeakyNun I don't see how, because one of the two terms in `Variance` is divided by `n` and the other by `n^2` and I don't see an easy way to undo those separately.

Comment: `Tr@#^2-#.#&@*Range` is only 18 bytes.

Comment: @MishaLavrov neat! Feel free to make it a separate answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
?:?:}+=-:(:(#{:**+**#2/!
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Pzo_On0rPS06KDooI3s6KiorKiojMi8h&input=OTEgMTIz)

#### Explanation

Since loops tend to be expensive in Labyrinth, I figured the explicit formula should be shortest, as it can be expressed as linear code.

```
Cmd Explanation                 Stacks [ Main | Aux ]
?   Read M.                     [ M | ]
:   Duplicate.                  [ M M | ]
?   Read N.                     [ M M N | ]
:   Duplicate.                  [ M M N N | ]
}   Move copy to aux.           [ M M N | N ]
+   Add.                        [ M (M+N) | N ]
=   Swap tops of stacks.        [ M N | (M+N) ]
-   Subtract.                   [ (M-N) | (M+N) ]
:   Duplicate.                  [ (M-N) (M-N) | (M+N) ]
(   Decrement.                  [ (M-N) (M-N-1) | (M+N) ]
:   Duplicate.                  [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-1) | (M+N) ]
(   Decrement.                  [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) | (M+N) ]
#   Push stack depth.           [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) 3 | (M+N) ]
{   Pull (M+N) over from aux.   [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) 3 (M+N) | ]
:   Duplicate.                  [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) 3 (M+N) (M+N) | ]
*   Multiply.                   [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) 3 ((M+N)^2) | ]
*   Multiply.                   [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (M-N-2) (3*(M+N)^2) | ]
+   Add.                        [ (M-N) (M-N-1) (3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2) | ]
*   Multiply.                   [ (M-N) ((M-N-1)*(3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2)) | ]
*   Multiply.                   [ ((M-N)*(M-N-1)*(3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2)) | ]
#   Push stack depth.           [ ((M-N)*(M-N-1)*(3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2)) 1 | ]
2   Multiply by 10, add 2.      [ ((M-N)*(M-N-1)*(3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2)) 12 | ]
/   Divide.                     [ ((M-N)*(M-N-1)*(3*(M+N)^2 + M - N - 2)/12) | ]
!   Print.                      [ | ]
```

The instruction pointer then hits a dead end and has to turn around. When it now encounters `/` it attempts a division by zero (since the bottom of the stack is implicitly filled with zeros), which terminates the program.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```
a#b=sum[a..b]^2-sum(map(^2)[a..b])
```

Usage example: `91 # 123` -> `12087152`.

Nothing to explain.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 24 bytes

```
:efL:{:2^.}a+S,L+:2^:S-.
```

Expects the 2 numbers in Input as a list, e.g. `[91:123]`.

#### Explanation

```
:efL                     Find the list L of all integers in the range given in Input
    :{:2^.}a             Apply squaring to each element of that list
            +S,          Unify S with the sum of the elements of that list
               L+:2^     Sum the elements of L, then square the result
                    :S-. Unify the Output with that number minus S
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>36 32</s>  31 bytes

```perl6
{([+] $_=@_[0]..@_[1])²-[+] $_»²}
{([+] $_=$^a..$^b)²-[+] $_»²}
{[+]($_=$^a..$^b)²-[+] $_»²}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##VY7BDsFAFEX38xV3MZGZmDZtUUoqPsJOkGIqjWrLTIXgp2zt@mM1KiQ2L/ed3HffLeQx9etSSZx8ez0ibzWVSo8I2V8w0UYqhGAEYD0RcIRjBH1HvPfAFa7XaZDrOYO@2/MabrDTUM/vGic3WUUaZWh/4j7RrU0Sx5Y6WLmZ5R5hfZ2154wuQ7qIbJsuVrx6WAaBLqtn9bjXcX78FrLGhoJhuJMXNkmyotRcYHiK0lIyKs@FXGu54eC4mkKJwv8zdvvd/MwC9jZRmtzrFw)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{ # bare block with placeholder parameters $a and $b

  [+](# reduce with &infix:<+>
      # create a range, and store it in $_
      $_ = $^a .. $^b
  )²
  -
  [+] # reduce with &infix:<+>
    # square each element of $_ ( possibly in parallel )
    $_»²
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  (5,9) => 970,
  (91,123) => 12087152,
  (1,10) => 2640,
);

plan +@tests;

my &diff-sq-of-sum = {[+]($_=$^a..$^b)²-[+] $_»²}

for @tests -> $_ ( :key(@input), :value($expected) ) {
  is diff-sq-of-sum(|@input), $expected, .gist
}
```

```
1..3
ok 1 - (5 9) => 970
ok 2 - (91 123) => 12087152
ok 3 - (1 10) => 2640
```

Comment: Save a byte moving the assignment and evading parens: `{$_=$^a..$^b;.sum²-[+] $_»²}`

Comment: 25 bytes: `{.sum²-[+] $_»²}o&[..]`

Answer (score 3):

### Matlab, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

Using Suever's idea of `norm` gives us 2 bytes less

```
@(x,y)sum(x:y)^2-norm(x:y)^2
```

Old (simple) version:

```
@(x,y)sum(x:y)^2-sum((x:y).^2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```
@(x,y)sum(z=x:y)^2-z*z'
```

Creates an anonymous function named `ans` which accepts two inputs: `ans(lower, upper)`

[**Online Demo**](http://ideone.com/b9zIwP)

**Explanation**

Creates a row vector from `x` to `y` (inclusive) and stores it in `z`. We then sum all the elements using `sum` and square it (`^2`). To compute the sum of the squares, we perform matrix multplication between the row-vector and it's transpose. This will effectively square each element and sum up the result. We then subtract the two.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>50</s> 37 bytes

```
f=(n,m,s=0)=>n>m?0:2*n*s+f(n+1,m,n+s)
```

Now a port of @Dennis♦'s Python solution.

Comment: Try using ```n=>m=>eval(`for(s=t=0;n<=m;t+=n++)s+=n*n;t*t-s`)```

Comment: @MamaFunRoll On the other hand, I could try porting Dennis♦'s Python solution...

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 36 bytes

```
m#n=sum[2*i*j|i<-[m..n],j<-[i+1..n]]
```

---

```
λ> m # n = sum [ 2*i*j | i <- [m..n], j <- [i+1..n] ]
λ> 5 # 9
970
λ> 91 # 123
12087152
λ> 1 # 10
2640
```

Note that

$$\left( \sum_{k=m}^n k \right)^2 -  \sum_{k=m}^n k^2 = \cdots =  \sum_{k_1=m}^n  \sum_{k_2=m\\ k_2 \neq k_1}^n k_1 k_2 = \sum_{k_1=m}^n  \sum_{k_2=k_1+1}^n 2 \,k_1 k_2$$

Comment: You don't need the parens around `i+1`.

Comment: Also if you want to talk Haskell and Haskell golfing you can join us in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men).

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>84</s> 77 characters, <s>84</s> 77 bytes

7 bytes smaller due to Martin Ender and FryAmTheEggMan, thank you.

`public int a(int b,int c){int e=0,f=0;for(;b<=c;e+=b,f+=b*b++);return e*e-f;}`

Using the three test cases in the original post: http://ideone.com/q9MZSZ

Ungolfed:

```
public int g(int b, int c) {
    int e = 0, f = 0;
    for (; b <= c; e += b, f += b * b++);
    return e*e-f;
}
```

Process is fairly self-explanatory. I declared two variables to represent the square of the sums and the sum of the squares and repeatedly incremented them appropiately. Finally, I return the computed difference.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can probably save a byte by putting that `++` on `f+=b*b++` (so you can leave the third slot of the `for` empty) and you also don't need to square `e` before returning it (i.e. just do `return e*e-f`).

Comment: Actually instead of leaving the third slot of the `for` empty, move the `f+=b*b++` in there, so you can save on both a semicolon and the braces.

Comment: Great catch @MartinEnder, thank you :)

Comment: Also based on what Martin had in mind, [this](http://ideone.com/q9MZSZ) seems to be a bit shorter.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Oh, I wasn't aware that you could have multiple statements in the third slot of the for-loop, thanks to you as well.

Comment: Apparently, my last comment was incorrect. It is actually a special part of the Java grammar: the final statement of a for is actually a special kind of statement, which is called a statement expression list. This special statement can have more than one statement joined by a comma. See [14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) (you'll have to navigate there yourself, I couldn't find a way to make a more precise link) of the language specification.

Comment: You can also move e+=b outside for loop (http://ideone.com/2rgZSh). This will save you one more character

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```
f=(x,y,s=0,p=0)=>x<=y?f(x+1,y,s+x,p+x*x):s*s-p
```

Answer (score 3):

## Factor, 48 bytes

```
[ [a,b] [ [ sq ] map sum ] [ sum sq ] bi - abs ]
```

An anonymous function.

```
[ 
  [a,b] ! a range from a to b 
  [ 
    [ sq ] map sum ! anonymous function: map sq over the range and sum the result 
  ] 
  [ sum sq ] ! the same thing, in reverse order
  bi - abs   ! apply both anon funcs to the range, subtract them and abs the result
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 108 bytes(36 chars)

```
방빠방빠쌍다쌍상싸사타빠밤타빠받다파반다받상싸사빠따따다따따받밤따나망히
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1hpWvdy6AkG96el93LwGSb5ob33TveNO05m1zA1h2CYwxG6jgbU/P6w0zgAwgF64SJDtlAwgBxSEMoOINYHbTjNfL576d1/H/v6mCJQA)

---

Takes two inputs from user(separated by line feed or whitespace) and print result of following function;

> \$f(a,b)=((a-b)\cdot(a-b-1)\cdot(3\cdot(a+b)^2+a-b-2))/12\$

Answer (score 2):

## APL, <s>23</s> 20 bytes

```
-/+/¨2*⍨{(+/⍵)⍵}⎕..⎕
```

Works in NARS2000.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
&:ts2^w2^s-
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Jjp0czJedzJecy0&input=NQo5)

Explanation:

```
&:           #Create a range from the input
  t          #Duplicate it
   s2^       #Sum it and square it
      w      #swap the two ranges
       2^s   #Square it and sum it
          -  #Take the difference
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 47 bytes

Two variations

```
param($n,$m)$n..$m|%{$o+=$_;$p+=$_*$_};$o*$o-$p

$args-join'..'|iex|%{$o+=$_;$p+=$_*$_};$o*$o-$p
```

In both cases we're generating a range with the `..` operator, piping that to a loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we're accumulating `$o` and `$p` as either the sum or the sum-of-squares. We then calculate the square-of-sums with `$o*$o` and subtract `$p`. Output is left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
s*M-F#^}FQ2
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2aM-F%23%5E%7DFQ2&input=91%2C123&debug=0)

```
s*M-F#^}FQ2
       }FQ    Compute the range
      ^   2   Generate all pairs
   -F#        Remove those pairs who have identical elements
 *M           Product of all pairs
s             Sum.
```

Comment: Nice usage of filter. Though there is already a build-in for this task: `s*M.P}FQ2`

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 10 bytes

```
õV
x²aUx ²
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9VYKeLJhVXggsg==&input=NSw5)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
rµÄḋḊḤ
```

Recent improvements to the Jelly language allow a compact implementation of the \$g\$ function from [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83369/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9qZWxsef//csK1w4ThuIvhuIrhuKT///85Mf8xMjM)

#### How it works

```
rµÄḋḊḤ  Main link. Arguments: a, b (integers)


r       Range; yield R := [a, ..., b].
 µ      Begin a monadic chain with argument R.
  Ä     Accumulate; take the cumulative sum of R.
    Ḋ   Deque; yield [a+1, ..., b].
   ḋ    Take the dot product, ignoring the last term of the cumulative sum.
     Ḥ  Unhalve; double the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ṡ:²∑$∑²ε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuaE6wrLiiJEk4oiRwrLOtSIsIiIsIjkxXG4xMjMiXQ==)

### How?

```
ṡ:²∑$∑²ε
ṡ        # Inclusive range between (implicit) second input and (implicit) first input
 :       # Duplicate this range
  ²      # Square each of the duplicate
   ∑     # Summate
    $    # Swap so the other range is at the top
     ∑   # Summate
      ²  # Then square
       ε # Absolute difference between the two
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
IDS²s²S-
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqzxdgg9tKj60KVh3SXFScjFUeMFiUy5LCBMA)

##### Explanation

```python
IDS²s²S-  # Implicit input
ID        # Inclusive range; duplicate
  S²      # Sum the list; square the sum
    s     # Swap so the range is back on top
     ²S   # Square each item; sum the list
       -  # Take the difference
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 17 bytes

```
q~),>_:+2#\2f#:+-
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~)%2C%3E_%3A%2B2%23%5C2f%23%3A%2B-&input=91%20123)

#### Explanation

```
q~       e# Read and evaluate input, dumping M and N on the stack.
),       e# Increment, create range [0 1 ... N].
>        e# Discard first M elements, yielding [M M+1 ... N].
_        e# Duplicate.
:+2#     e# Sum and square.
\2f#:+   e# Swap with other copy. Square and sum.
-        e# Subtract.
```

Alternatively, one can just sum the products of all distinct pairs (basically multiplying out the square of the sum, and removing squares), but that's a byte longer:

```
q~),>2m*{)-},::*:+
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```
a=>b=>([s=q=0,...Array(b-a)].map((_,i)=>q+=(s+=(n=i+a),n*n)),s*s-q)
```

### Test Suite

```js
f=a=>b=>([s=q=0,...Array(b-a)].map((_,i)=>q+=(s+=(n=i+a),n*n)),s*s-q)
e=s=>`${s} => ${eval(s[0])}` // template tag format for tests
console.log(e`f(5)(9)`)
console.log(e`f(91)(123)`)
console.log(e`f(1)(10)`)
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 29 bytes

Port of [Doorknob's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83344/48934).

```
[:(+/@(^&2)-~2^~+/)[}.[:i.1+]
```

### Usage

```
>> f = [:(+/@(^&2)-~2^~+/)[}.[:i.1+]
>> 91 f 123x
<< 12087152
```

Where `>>` is STDIN, `<<` is STDOUT, and `x` is for extended precision.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 11 bytes

```
h1:Ds]MXXs-
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=h1%3ADs%5DMXXs-&input=9%0A5)

```
h1:         - inclusive_range(input)
   Ds]      -     [^, sum(^)]
      MX    -    deep_map(^, <--**2)
         s  -   ^[1] = sum(^[1])
          - -  ^[0]-^[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 25 bytes

```
f(a,b,x=a:b)=sum(x)^2-x'x
```

This is a function that accepts two integers and returns a 1x1 integer array.

The approach is simple: Construct a `UnitRange` from the endpoints `a` and `b` and call it `x`, then sum `x`, square it, and subtract its norm, which is computed as `transpose(x) * x`.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZihhLGIseD1hOmIpPXN1bSh4KV4yLXgneAoKZm9yIHRlc3QgaW4gWyg1LDksOTcwKSwgKDkxLDEyMywxMjA4NzE1MiksICgxLDEwLDI2NDApXQogICAgYSwgYiwgZXhwZWN0ZWQgPSB0ZXN0CiAgICBwcmludGxuKGYoYSwgYikgPT0gW2V4cGVjdGVkXSkKZW5k&input=) (includes all test cases)

Comment: `a\b=-(x=a:b)'x+sum(x)^2` saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 19 bytes

```
Prompt N,M
randIntNoRep(N,M
sum(Ans)2-sum(Ans2
```

`randIntNoRep` gets the range (shuffled). The rest is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fith](https://github.com/nazek42/fith), 52 bytes

```
{ 1 + range dup sum 2 pow swap { 2 pow } map sum - }
```

This is an anonymous function that takes the two numbers on the stack and leaves a single number.

Explanation:

```
{
    1 + range dup      2 ranges from a to b inclusive
    sum 2 pow          Sum one and square it
    swap               Bring a fresh range to the top
    { 2 pow } map sum  Square every element and sum the list
    -                  Subtract
}
```

Comment: If you like postfix, point-free and stack-based functional prorgamming you might like [Factor](https://github.com/factor/factor) :D

Answer (score 1):

## GeoGebra, 91 bytes

```
a(x)=(x²+x)/2
b(x)=x³/3+x²/2+x/6
c(x,y)=(a(y)-a(x))²
d(x,y)=b(y)-b(x)
c(x-1,y)-d(x-1,y)
```

Defines a function (probably `e(x,y)`) that computes the desired difference.
`a(x)` calculates the sum of natural numbers between `0` and `x`.
`b(x)` calculates the sum of the squares of the natural numbers between `0` and `x`.
`c(x,y)` first computes the sum of the natural numbers between `x` and `y`, then squares that sum.
`d(x,y)` calculates the sum of squares between `b(x)` and `b(y)`.
The last line defines a multi-variable function that finishes the calculation. The function is automatically assigned a name, saving a few bytes.

Comment: Hi, how do I call the function that this defines? I was able to figure out the input at https://www.geogebra.org/classic#cas , but couldn't figure out how to find or call the final function.

Comment: @sundar: The last line is an expression in x and y. We could prepend `e(x,y)=` to give it a name, but to save bytes, we don’t here. GeoGebra automatically assigns the expression a name (probably e, since that’s the next available letter). I don’t have the environment available right now, but I wouldn’t use the CAS pane. The algebra pane and input bar should do the job right. (It’s been a while since I used GGb online; my mental image of it may be outdated.)

Answer (score 1):

### R - 33 bytes

```
x=scan():scan();sum(x)^2-sum(x^2)
```

pass your lower limit to the first `scan` then your upper limit to the second `scan`

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 90 bytes

```
> Input
> Input
> 2
>> 1…2
>> L*3
>> Each 5 4
>> ∑6
>> ∑4
>> 8*3
>> 9-7
>> Output 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hAtBG3HZ2SkYPmpYBmb4aBmDKNfE5AwFUwUTEPtRx0QzKA3mW0CUWOqagyj/0hKgOQqGBv//m3JZAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
r->sum(r)^2-sum(r.^2)
```

Returns an anonymous function that takes a `Range`, eg `f(1:10)`, which then returns the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0jXrrg0V6NIM85IF8zQizPS/J@al8LlUJyRX66QpmFoZWigCeeZWllq/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](http://gcc.gnu.org), 67 bytes

```
f(n,m){double a,b;for(;n<=m;a+=n,b+=pow(n++,2));return pow(a,2)-b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBbsMgEEX3PsXIVSq7JolqqYuKOEfoBdIsMAYbFYYIsKMqytVLbSdpKrVsGN78P5oPX7acxweFXPeNgI0PjbKrbpvckWGhm0hj@1oLkJnCAEhgukxOk1tjvYY3G6Bjg8IWQqc8aIUCjtZ9jKXlTOtPAgdnjfJiFWWGxOSnq5uRmkrrMoqbylBWVEjqojrYY4ZFQco8p06E3iFMiI1gWdNznHdgCuedmGs5Ad4x9zSWw26fnxIYj5LZ1NqW1/fMLhkM/SHec4azctg97wmkiyYl8Ij5/5LyLjG/JAc3TpZZupDvmJJLxGv7DEJ7Aac/2unXBNq@7aYIvREY/Gq033zJOcaX@PrFpWatj0ttvgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```c
a,b;f(n,m){for(a=b=0;m/n;a+=n++)b+=n*n;n=a*a-b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LDoJADEX3fkVDohlgUMGVmeAn@APIooy8EqcYXhvCt48D4iPRbnrbe26TSi@XUmvkicgYcWUPWVUzDJNwL9SOBLohua6dmOaQoBAd9BIx6pJaUFgSmwTWueQgC6wdI/sotocVmCozNlmnYJnnneGJgxLvTdNIpJnsIz/mYK2vFocN2f@R4IOoL@Rem8sZM86FLP78ZbFHSG9NCsMPe65aSKnq8mJ6oVMptc3WxF@51aj10dd@cHgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 70 bytes

```
func[a b][s: t: 0 until[s: s + a t: a * a + t  b < a: a + 1]s * s - t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchLCoMwGEXhuas444qQKA4SuopOQwbxERAkiPldfxoLdXDhfudcl/JZF@ebaEu80uwCk3fZIhbFlWTbb2Vawt0Cr7oWgYk3wf6kfa490yG@HOeWhMiIaf7faHQ/PKxS5Qs)

Answer (score 1):

### Excel, 60 bytes

```
=(B1^2+B1-A1^2+A1)^2/4-(2*B1^3+3*B1^2+B1-2*A1^3+3*A1^2-A1)/6
```

Algebraic reshuffling of more verbose implementation:
For inputs `a` and `b`:

```
(B1*(B1+1)-A1*(A1-1))/2          // (Sum of b) - (Sum of a-1)
(  )^2                           //  squared
B1*(B1+1)*(2*B1+1)/6             //  Sum of (b squared)
A1*(A1-1)*(2*A1-1)/6             //  Sum of (a-1 squared)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 62 bytes

```cs
(a,b)=>{int x=0,y=0;for(;a<=b;a++){x+=a;y+=a*a;}return x*x-y;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLasMwEDzbX7G3SLFiOwk9BEWBUigU2ktTyKHkoDhyEdhS0COxMf52Vw74UGh7GXZ2lpndLeyi0EYM3kr1BfvWOlFTKCpuLTxCF1vHnSzg2atiK5UjMMEOSmAD4uSE2a4LDWhYTlqW01IbRPmWnShPEtw1CeO0DTDntDfCeaOgmTeLlvYDnfyvWp7hjUuFcBdHT1pZXYn0YKQTr1IJVKIHssGY/q5tlmS5Wv8pBzW/i3GUZRAu0XUtwsKyhFZ7uPFQOw3eipEb0DcVLrx4F2dZZJ0ZP2OBweT9Lvj5bo0p/MgLWYFfhXHph35Rbr1CNt1fKunQjMzwZ37EBP6dWB7xuGnfD98)

Ungolfed:

```cs
(a, b) => {                 // takes in two integer inputs, delimited by a comma
    int x = 0, y = 0;       // initializes x and y
    for(; a <= b; a++)      // increment a until a equals b
    {
        x += a;             // add current a to x
        y += a * a;         // add square of current a to y
    }
    return (x * x) - y;     // return the difference of the square of the sums (x*x) and the sum of the squares (y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:sum(x*y*2for x in range(a,b+1)for y in range(x+1,b+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxDoMwDADn9hXeYhMPDagDSP0JS1CbFqkxKAQpeX1KWLqd7qRbc/ws0hX3GMvX@ulpwfI0bLvH1OSmdUuABLNAsPJ@4dG0oSrzXyZtTk2lBvQsVCPeuScG7A2btqt0wI2G62UNs0TcYkBPWrHSFYVYjVGxOwdUfg)

with @Dennis formulae and w/o recursion, yet another Python solution (as I cannot comment @leaky-nun solution (not enough reputation)

Comment: This is code-golf, you should try to make your code as short as possible. At least remove the unnecessary whitespaces. Try merging two `for` loops into one if possible.

Comment: Sorry @user202729, this is actually my first contribution. I've edited using your comment and reformatted contribution using TIO.

Comment: Did it for the first and forgot it for the second... thanks @Stephen

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 58 bytes

```
for([,$p,$q]=$argv;$p<=$q;$s+=$p++)$t+=$p*$p;echo$s*$s-$t;
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abdcea8b2f5341a8631da00d0012d14701eb0259).

Answer (score 1):

## [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

> Translation of: [my Factor solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83601/46231)

```ruby
{|a,b|R=a..b;R.map{.sqr}.sum-R.sum.sqr->abs}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85MSU37/784sVKhuiZRJ6kmyDZRTy/JOkgvN7GgWq@4sKhWr7g0VzcIRIK4unaJScW1ekWleRomOkYGmv@BAAA)

use it like `x.run(4, 20)` -> 38760

Previous

```ruby
->(a,b,R=a..b){R.map{.sqr}.sum-R.sum.sqr->abs}
```

longer, explained

```ruby
->                       # the next list is a function parameter list
(a, b, R = a .. b )      # R is a RangeNum over the a and b 
{                        # a Block
  return                 # return the whole expression
  R.map{ |n|             # map this Block over the range
    return n.sqr         # squared value
  }.sum                  # summed the range
  -                      # subtract
  R.sum.sqr              # sum of the range, squared
  ->abs                  # call Number.abs on everything on the left-hand side of ->
}                        # ok, we're done
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 76 <s>80</s> bytes

```
proc S l\ u {while \$l<=$u {incr Q $l
append R -$l*$l
incr l}
expr $Q**2+$R}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCoMwEAXv@xXvsKeUQrX0ILQfoR5rDxIDClu7REMLkm@PoXgZGAZmtZKS@o9FC@kQsH3HSRw6lvuDs06z9ajBQr2qmwc0OLOY7P8ikdxPPbg2pjxxE5O8ez1WdENFVYGivFLmhSI2DeuCZ5uH4PCKaQc)

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque - 16 bytes

```
r@J++2?^j)S[++?-

r@                  range
  J                 dup
   ++               sum
     2?^            square it
        j           swap
         )S[        map (square)
            ++      sum
              ?-    subtract
```

**Alternate versions:**

```
r@JJ?*++j++S[?-ab
r@J++2?^jqS[ms?-
r@J++J?*jqS[ms?-
r@J++J?*jJ?*++?-
r@J)S[++j++S[j?-
```

^- and this is the art of golfing :(.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 67 bytes

```
|b,e|{let mut t=0;let mut s=0;for i in b..=e{t+=i;s+=i*i;}(t*t)-s};
```

A closure that takes two integers and returns an integer.

Answer (score 1):

## Pony, 73 bytes

```pony
fun f(m:U64,n:U64,s:U64=0):U64=>if m>n then 0 else(2*m*s)+f(m+1,n,m+s)end
```

sort of ungolfed

```pony
  fun apply(m: U64, n: U64, s: U64 = 0): U64 =>
    if m > n then 0
    else (2 * m * s) + apply(m + 1, n, m + s) end
```

Port of [Neil's JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83365/46231).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 24 bytes

```
{(t*t:+/s)-+/s*s:x_!1+y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNEq8RKW79YUxdIaBVbVcQrGmpX1v5P01PXMFWwtLY0VDA0MrYGkgaa/wE)

"Boring" but straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>42</s> 35 bytes

```
$=>[-*<=∑r∑map r:<=&..&'z->z*z]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?5XUWo9)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 49 bytes

Without recursion:

```
(b,e)=>eval('for(x=y=0;b<=e;y+=b*b++)x+=b;x*x-y')
```

Try it:

```js
f=(b,e)=>eval('for(x=y=0;b<=e;y+=b*b++)x+=b;x*x-y')

console.log(f(5,9)); // 970
console.log(f(91,123)); // 12087152
console.log(f(1,10)); // 2640
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 8 bytes

```
ŘĐĐƩ²↔·-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9weXT//8WYxJDEkMapwrLihpTCty3//zkKNQ)

Takes two inputs on separate lines as `max`, `min`

```
Ř               implicit inputs; Řange
 ĐĐ             Đuplicate array on stack twice
   Ʃ²           Get square of sum
     ⇹·         Get sum of squares
       -        Subtract; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 22 bytes

```
nnR&s&+:*>l[:*sp<l->]<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z8vL0itWE3bSssuJ9pKq7jAJkfXLtbm/39LQy5DI2MA)

This is a straight forward interpretation of the rules...

```
nnR                     - get the start/end, generate the sequence of numbers
   &s                   - save the sequence...
     &+                 - sum it
       :*               - square the sum
         >l             - load the sequence on a new stack
           [        ]   - while the stack isn't empty
            :*          - square the number
              sp<l      - move the squared number to the other stack
                  ->    - subtract and go back to the second stack
                     <  - switch back to the accumulator stack
                        - the number on the stack prints automatically on exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 33 bytes

```ruby
:!~|:-%[:sum|g= ~:**&2,:*&g|:sum]
```

(The space between `=` and `~` is necessary to keep the Ruby lexer from interpreting them as the `=~` operator.)

### Explanation

```
:!~ | :- % [:sum | g = ~:** & 2, :* & g | :sum]

:!~ |                                            # Range, then
      :- % [                   ,              ]  # difference of...
            :sum | g = ~:** & 2                  #   sum, then square (save the square function in g), and
                                 :* & g | :sum   #   map with square, then sum
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWNxWtFOtqrHRVo62KS3Nr0m0V6qy0tNSMdKy01NJrQGKxEIUrChTcok11LKHcBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 62 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:sum(range(a,b+1))**2-sum(x*x for x in range(a,b+1))
```

Or, longer:

```python
lambda a,b:sum(sum(x*y for y in range(a,b+1)if x-y)for x in range(a,b+1))
```

[Ideone both!](http://ideone.com/sGF1Xb)

Comment: This seems to be 63 bytes? (Did you forget the `lambda a,b:`?) Anyway, it seems like the naive: `lambda a,b:sum(range(a,b+1))**2-sum(x*x for x in range(a,b+1))` is a byte shorter, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this works, just ran it against the test and 5,9 yields 995?

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 95 bytes

```java
public int d(int a,int b){int i=a,j,s=0;for(;i<=b;i++)for(j=a;j<=b;j++)s+=i==j?0:i*j;return s;}
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/HirPaw)

Answer (score 0):

## Actually, 11 bytes

```
u@x;♂²Σ@Σ²-
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=dUB4O-KZgsKyzqNAzqPCsi0&input=OTEKMTIz)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 23 bytes

```
sum(i:j)^2-sum((i:j)^2)
```

Does pretty much what you expect by taking i and j as inputs.

Comment: you can save a byte by assigning the range to a variable in the first sum. `sum(a<-i:j)^2-sum(a^2)`

Comment: This assumes that the variables `i` and `j` are already defined, which makes this a snippet. By default we require all submissions to be either full programs which take input from STDIN and print output to STDOUT, or functions that accept arguments and return values. You can fix this by prepending `function(i,j)` to the beginning.

Comment: In fact, all of your answers on the site thus far appear to be snippets. Please adjust them to be programs or functions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, 10 bytes

```
u@x;;*@Σ²-
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=dUB4OzsqQM6jwrIt&input=NQo5)

Explanation:

```
u@x;;*@Σ²-
u@x         range(a, b+1)
   ;;       two copies
     *      dot product with itself (equal to sum of squares)
      @Σ²   sum remaining copy, square sum
         -  subtract
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5.10, 41 bytes

```
map{$s+=$_,$r+=$_**2}(<>..<>);say$s**2-$r
```

Input is given on 2 lines, for instance:

```
61
127
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/9JQcSD)

Answer (score 0):

## [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), 49 Bytes

`f=(n,m,s=0)->if n>m then 0else 2*n*s+f(n+1,m,n+s)`

Translation of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83365/55821)

Output:

`f 91, 123 == 12087152
 => true`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, <strike>82 bytes</strike> 85 bytes

```
def a(l, u):
    c=0
    d=0
    for e in range(l, u+1):
        c+=e
        d+=e**2
    return c**2-d
```

Works in base 10.

Comment: Currently your answer is invalid (use the test cases to verify it): 1. You forgot to square `c` 2. You have to subtract the sum of squares from the square of the sum, so `c**2-d` 3. I suggest to golf your code, and you can count newlines as one byte instead of two 4. I suggest adding a [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7NDoMgEITP7FPshSiKjdr0oA19FyPYklA0/DTx6Sl4@ZLZmZ3McYbPbseUpNpwqQ2PbAayCil6INvuUKG26Bb7VsVsBzavrVBPmdE0IxCnQnQW1yw6mfT32F1Af3qA8m20vQry4eaD1DaXG44RBarfYuriMyCH0zZgRT1H6rF7ZVZIsS5Rfs3CyFh68AmmgQ/jHTL7Pw "Python 2 – Try It Online") link

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
r->2triu(r*r',1)|>sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@5@mYPu/SNfOqKQos1SjSKtIXcdQs8auuDT3v0NxRn65QpqGoZWhgSYXjGdqZan5HwA)

Julia port of [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83347/8774). Comes out to the same bytecount as the other Julia answer by @gggg. Takes a `Range` similar to that answer, does a matrix multiply of it with its transpose to get all pairwise products in a matrix. Takes the upper triangular portion of that (the 1 argument is to denote the distance from the leading diagonal to start from), multiplies that by 2, and finally sums the values and returns that implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Tr@#^2-#.#&@*Range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n1aaZ/s/pMhBOc5IV1lPWc1BKygxLz31f0BRZl5JdDVQOtpUxzJWRwHEsjTUUTA0MobyDA1ia2P/AwA)

Composition of `Tr@#^2-#.#&` (square of sum minus sum of squares, where sum of squares is implemented via dot product) and `Range` (list of all integers between the two inputs). If you like seeing the operations in order, `Range/*Tr@#^2-#.#&` is equivalent.

As a bonus, also solves [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175236/sum-square-difference) with no modifications, since `Range` can either take one argument (giving the range from `1` to the input) or two. (But it's not the most efficient solution possible there.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>74</s> 65 bytes

```bash
x=y=0;for i in `seq $1 $2`;{ x=$[x+i];y=$[y+i*i]; };echo $[x*x-y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8K20tbAOi2/SCFTITNPIaE4tVBBxVBBxSjBulqhwlYlukI7M9a6Esio1M7UAjIVaq1TkzPyFYAyWhW6lbH///83/W8JAA)

I'm no expert at bash golfing, but this works.
Managed to cut 9 bytes just by reading through the bash golfing tips thread

Comment: `for((i=$1;i<=$2;x+=i,y+=i*i++)){ :;};echo $[x*x-y]` saves 15 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 105 bytes

```
proc d a\ b {while {[incr a]<=$b} {set j $a
while \$j<=$b {incr p [expr 2*([incr j]-1)*($a-1)]}}
expr $p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwFAX3OcVbZFELgqm4KOhJ0r9I04ANRT9pikLI2WNtEVePYeZFO5XC4WkxwHTokV73cXJIenzYAEPXm@wz0uwiPKQRu@6k/wqkrWJo9@aApq72m6ejOtSVNOtQzmKzknPhJc7QAy5oSfygVVDN@c8rnqh8AA)

<s># [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 112 bytes</s>

```
proc d a\ b {set i [expr $a-1]
while \$i<$b {set j [incr i]
while \$j<$b {incr p [expr 2*[incr j]*$i]}}
expr $p}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 34 bytes

```
[ [a,b] dup Σ sq swap norm-sq - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxDcIwFAV7T/EGIBEJogg0dIiGBlFFKT7OBywS23w7IOZhH1YygTQn3Ul3Jh2dpONht9@u0FO85oM12rU8iZC9cMCNxXL3T1N/8O8L8MIxvrwYG7FWaolKVQWKcqFGzlONmmanBu3g8Xkj3BGe5GGd9NkoGZpURjEb5AG6Y5L0BQ)

- `[a,b]` Create a range from the input.
- `dup Σ sq swap` Square of sum.
- `norm-sq` Sum of squares.
- `-` Subtract.