# Sum square difference

Tags: code-golf, math

The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is,
\$1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + 10^2 = 385\$

The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is,

\$(1 + 2 + ... + 10)^2 = 55^2 = 3025\$

Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum is

\$3025 − 385 = 2640\$

For a given input n, find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first n natural numbers and the square of the sum.

Test cases

```
1       => 0
2       => 4
3       => 22
10      => 2640
24      => 85100
100     => 25164150
```

This challenge was first announced at [Project Euler #6](https://projecteuler.net/problem=6).

#### Winning Criteria

- There are no rules about what should be the behavior with negative or zero input.
- The shortest answer wins.

Comment: [A052149](http://oeis.org/A052149)

Comment: This challenge needs a winning criterion (e.g. code golf)

Comment: This is a subset of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83338/66833) question

Comment: Can the sequence be 0 indexed? i.e. the natural numbers up to `n`?

Comment: Note that [it's discouraged to post challenges directly taken from somewhere else](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1082/69850).

Comment: @Enigma I really don't think that this is a duplicate of the target since many answers here don't port easily to be answers of that, so this adds something.

Comment: #APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

    {+/⍵×⍵×⍵-1}∘⍳

use the formula Sum[w=1..n](w*w*(w-1)) test:

      g←{+/⍵×⍵×⍵-1}∘⍳
      g 0
    0
      g 1
    0
      g 2
    4
      g 3
    22
      g 10
    2640

Comment: @JonathanAllan: You need to spell my name correctly for me to receive a ping ;) Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this just the other challenge with **a** hardcoded to 1? In my opinion that is close enough to warrant a dupe, but if I'm alone with that opinion, feel free to vote to reopen.

Comment: @Emigna wow, donnu how I manegad ttah, sorry :) porting an answer from there to here is easy, but probably not the golfiest, porting back seems non-trivial for the golfiest of solutions here; therefore I feel like this, while the same topic, justifies a separate question. (BTW I cannot "vote" to reopen, just hammer :( - I'll wait for other opinions)

Comment: @Emigna That makes sense, but in this case I think the challenge is simple enough that a small difference makes a big difference. The answers here are all about finding the most concise formula for the answer; almost none of the answers to the other question work that way.

Comment: very closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83338

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḋ²ḋṖ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq5Dmx7u6H64c9r///8NDQwA)**

#### How?

Implements  \$\sum_{i=2}^n{(i^2(i-1))}\$...

```
Ḋ²ḋṖ - Link: non-negative integer, n
Ḋ    - dequeue (implicit range)       [2,3,4,5,...,n]
 ²   - square (vectorises)            [4,9,16,25,...,n*n]
   Ṗ - pop (implicit range)           [1,2,3,4,...,n-1]
  ḋ  - dot product                    4*1+9*2+16*3+25*4+...+n*n*(n-1)
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>28</s>  27 bytes

-1 thanks to xnor

```python
lambda n:(n**3-n)*(n/4+1/6)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPSiNPS8tYN09TSyNP30TbUN9M839afpFCSWpxiUJmnoKGoY6RjrGOoYGOkQmQNNC04lIAgoKizLwSDZAiHQV1XTt1HYU0ME9T8z8A)**

Implements \$n(n-1)(n+1)(3n+2)/12\$

---

Python 2,  <s>29</s>  28 bytes: [`lambda n:(n**3-n)*(3*n+2)/12`](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAgEADvvWJvqW2U2kmol3QxShJqDfPS682aw8DAXE/aA6nsxjkf9lxWC2QYCaFb4oJpQY3inSxDiJC2O4EnYBIVapQ9qqG456aCwhU9pX9CqNupRnDsK55f)

Comment: You can shave a byte with `n*~-n**2*` or `(n**3-n)*`.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes

```apl
1⊥⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/BR19JHvZsPTwcThrqPelcAWf/THrVNeNTb96hvqqf/o67mQ@uNH7VNBPKCg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAUjrjQFYyA2NAAA)

#### How it works

```apl
1⊥⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳
  ⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳  Compute (x^3 - x^2) for 1..n
1⊥          Sum
```

Uses the fact that "square of sum" is equal to "sum of cubes".

Comment: For me 1⊥⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳ is not a function ; I tried 1⊥⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳10 and for me not compile...

Comment: @RosLuP You have to assign it to a variable first (as I did in the TIO link) or wrap it inside a pair of parentheses, as `(1⊥⍳×⍳×1-⍨⍳)10`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> <s>68</s> 64 bytes

```
((([{}])){({}())}{})([{({}())({})}{}]{(({}())){({})({}())}{}}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fQ0Mjuro2VlOzWqO6VkNTs7a6VhMoAuEASZBAbLUGhA9WpAlXCFL7//9/QwMA)

Pretty simple way of doing it with a couple of tricky shifts.  Hopefully someone will find some more tricks to make this even shorter.

Answer (score 7):

## TI-Basic (TI-83 series), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
sum(Ans² nCr 2/{2,3Ans
```

Implements \$\binom{n^2}{2}(\frac12 + \frac1{3n})\$. 
Takes input in `Ans`: for example, run `10:prgmX` to compute the result for input `10`.

Comment: Nice use of `nCr`!

Answer (score 5):

## Japt `-x`, <s>9</s> <s>8</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
õ²í*
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=9bLtKg==&input=MjQKLXg=)

---

### Explanation

```
õ        :Range [1,input]
 ²       :Square each
  í      :Interleave with 0-based indices
   *     :Reduce each pair by multiplication
         :Implicit output of the sum of the resulting array
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 20 bytes

```
f=n=>n&&n*n*--n+f(n)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i5PTS1PK09LVzdPO00jT/N/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaRiabmfwA)

Comment: what deviltry is this

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
ＩΣＥＮ×ιＸ⊕ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sUDDMy@5KDU3Na8kNQXILigt8SvNTUot0tDU1FHwzcwrLdYIyC8H8jN1FIyBQnCOkSYYWP//b2jwX7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: \$ ( \sum_1^n x )^2 = \sum_1^n x^3 \$ so \$ ( \sum_1^n x )^2 - \sum_1^n x^2 = \sum_1^n (x^3 - x^2) = \sum_1^n (x - 1)x^2 = \sum_0^{n-1} x(x + 1)^2 \$.

```
   Ｎ        Input number
  Ｅ         Map over implicit range i.e. 0 .. n - 1
        ι   Current value
       ⊕    Incremented
         ²  Literal 2
      Ｘ     Power
     ι      Current value
    ×       Multiply
 Σ          Sum
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{sum (1..$_)>>²Z*^$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q4NFdBw1BPTyVe087u0KYorTiV@Nr/xYmVCmkKhtZcEIYRjGEMYxgawOVMEGIG1v8B)

Uses the construction \$ \sum_{i=1}^n {(i^2(i-1))} \$

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 16 bytes

```
?dd3^r-r3*2+*C/p
```

Implements \$(n^3-n)(3n+2)/12\$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98@JcU4rki3yFjLSFvLWb/g/39DAwA)

Answer (score 3):

## APL(Dyalog), 17 bytes

```
{+/(¯1↓⍵)×1↓×⍨⍵}⍳
```

(Much longer) Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1pbX@PQesNHbZMf9W7VPDwdxDo8/VHvCiC39lHv5v9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moIRV5qCMRAbGgAA)

Comment: Go tacit and combine the drops: `+/¯1↓⍳×1⌽⍳×⍳`

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 16 bytes

```apl
((×⍨+/)-(+/×⍨))⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X0Pj8PRHvSu09TV1NbT1wWxNzUe9m/@nPWqb8Ki371HfVE//R13Nh9YbP2qbCOQFBzkDyRAPz@D/aQpGXGkKxkBsaAAA)

```apl
 (×⍨+/)            The square (× self) of the sum (+ fold)
       -           minus
        (+/×⍨)     the sum of the square
(             )⍳   of [1, 2, … input].
```

Comment: `(+/×⍨)` → `1⊥×⍨` as per [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153435/43319).

Comment: A further byte could be saved by keeping the `⍳` inside `(×⍨1⊥⍳)-⍳+.×⍳`

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>21</s> 17 bytes

<sup>*-4 bytes thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288).*</sup>

```
(3#+2)(#^3-#)/12&
```

Pure function. Takes an integer as input and returns an integer as output. Just implements the polynomial, since `Sum`s, `Range`s, `Tr`s, etc. take up a lot of bytes.

Comment: [`(3#+2)(#^3-#)/12&`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/Bfw1hZ20hTQznOWFdZU9/QSO1/QFFmXkm0soKunUJatHJsrIKagr6DQrWhjoKRjoKxjoKhAZBlAqINav8DAA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: It's possible to get there without just evaluating the polynomial: `#.(#^2-#)&@*Range` implements another common solution. (But it's also 17 bytes.) And we can implement the naive algorithm in 18 bytes: `Tr@#^2-#.#&@*Range`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 23 bytes

```java
n->(3*n+2)*(n*n*n-n)/12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Na8MwDIbv@RWiELAzx2vSnlo62HGHsUPZaezgJXFxlsjGVgqh5LdnTsIQQl/PK6lVd5W39e9semc9QRtrOZDppB6wImNRZuek6lQI8K4MwiMBcMNPZyoIpCiGuzU19HHGruQN3r6@Qflb4CsK8Ib0icqPH67xiqwHfZkxf2GHDJ9KnjHMouXIn4tyPq8KgxR3UBMowAUehYBSwEFAsY/ZcYn7aSO19SzSK3vaFP9nAa5joKaXdiDp4l@k2S491idI6xR3YoEFaKmc68bXEL9kS4vzbfOULD7Nfw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ÝDOnsnO-
```

Explanation:

```
ÝDOnsnO-     //Full program
Ý            //Push [0..a] where a is implicit input
 D           //Duplicate top of stack
  On         //Push sum, then square it
    s        //Swap top two elements of stack
     nO      //Square each element, then push sum
       -     //Difference (implicitly printed)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FwX/7ziPH/d//8NDQA)

Comment: `LDnOsOn-` was my first attempt too.

Answer (score 3):

### C, C++, <s>46</s> <s>40</s> 37 bytes ( #define ), <s>50</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes ( function )

-1 byte thanks to Zacharý

-11 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

Macro version :

```cpp
#define F(n)n*n*~n*~n/4+n*~n*(n-~n)/6
```

Function version :

```cpp
int f(int n){return~n*n*n*~n/4+n*~n*(n-~n)/6;}
```

Thoses lines are based on thoses 2 formulas :

Sum of numbers between 1 and n = `n*(n+1)/2` 
Sum of squares between 1 and n = `n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`

So the formula to get the answer is simply `(n*(n+1)/2) * (n*(n+1)/2) - n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`

And now to "optimize" the byte count, we break parenthesis and move stuff around, **while testing it always gives the same result**

`(n*(n+1)/2) * (n*(n+1)/2) - n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6` =>
`n*(n+1)/2*n*(n+1)/2 - n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6` =>
`n*(n+1)*n*(n+1)/4 - n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6`

Notice the pattern `p = n*n+1 = n*n+n`, so in the function, we declare another variable `int p = n*n+n` and it gives :

`p*p/4 - p*(2n+1)/6`

For `p*(p/4-(2*n+1)/6)` and so `n*(n+1)*(n*(n+1)/4 - (2n+1)/6)`, it works half the time only, and I suspect integer division to be the cause ( `f(3)` giving 24 instead of 22, `f(24)` giving 85200 instead of 85100, so we can't factorize the macro's formula that way, even if mathematically it is the same.

Both the macro and function version are here because of macro substitution :

F(3) gives `3*3*(3+1)*(3+1)/4-3*(3+1)*(2*3+1)/6 = 22` 
F(5-2) gives `5-2*5-2*(5-2+1)*(5-2+1)/4-5-2*(5-2+1)*(2*5-2+1)/6 = -30`

and mess up with the operator precedence. the function version does not have this problem

Comment: You **could** fix up the problem with the macros at the cost of A LOT of bytes by replacing all the `n` with `(n)`. Also, `F(n) n`=>`F(n)n` regardless.

Comment: It's possible to rearrange `return p*p/4-p*(n-~n)/6` to `return(p/4-(n-~n)/6)*p`.

Comment: @Zacharý No, it gives me bad results sometimes like 24 instead of 22 for input "3", or 85200 instead of 85100 for input "24". I suspect integer division to be the cause of that

Comment: Ugh, always forget about that.

Comment: 34 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs@2Lk8LBOvy9E20QZSWRp5uXZ6mvpl17X/lzLzknNKUVAWb4pKUzHy9DDsursy8EoXcxMw8jbL8zBTNai4FhYIioFiahpJqSkyeko5CmoahgaamNVftfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
{î²ï*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/68LpDmw6v19L@/9@Qy4jLmMvQgMvIBEgaAAA)

Calculates \$\sum_{k=1}^n (k^2(k-1))\$

#### Explanation:

```
{       Loop (implicit) input times
 î²     1-index of loop squared
    *   Multiplied by
   ï    The 0-index of the loop
     +  And add to the running total
```

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
b$)^2-c$
;$
;$$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/P0lFM85IN1mFyxqEVP7/NzQAAA)

### Explanation

```
 b$)^2-c$     First line
:             Implicit (output nth term in sequence)
 b$)          Each term in the sequence equals the second line at the current index
    ^2        squared
      -c$     minus the third line at the current index

;$            Second line - sum of integers up to n
;$$           Third line - sum of squares up to n
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

```javascript
n=>n*~-n*-~n*(n/4+1/6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5Pq043T0u3Lk9LI0/fRNtQ30zzf3J@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGoaYmF6qIEYaIMYaIoQGmNhMsqoDK/gMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>70</s> 69 bytes

```
 N =INPUT
I X =X + N ^ 3 - N ^ 2
 N =GT(N) N - 1 :S(I)
 OUTPUT =X
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/X8FPwdbTLyA0hMtTIULBNkJBGygSp2CsoAumjbhACtxDNPw0gQxdBUMFq2ANT00uBf/QEKAmoAYuVz@X//8NDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
sm**hdh
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2A%2Ahdh&input=10&debug=0).

Uses the formula in [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175268/41020).

```
sm**hdhddQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
             Trailing ddQ inferred
 m       Q   Map [0-Q) as d, using:
    hd         Increment d
   *  hd       Multiply the above with another copy
  *     d      Multiply the above by d
s            Sum, implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 58 bytes

```clj
(fn[s](-(Math/pow(reduce + s)2)(reduce +(map #(* % %)s))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMtL7o4VkNXwzexJEO/IL9coyg1pTQ5VUFboVjTSBPO08hNLFBQ1tBSUFVQ1SzWBIL//wE)

---

### Edit: I misunderstood the question

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <strike>55</strike>, 35 bytes

```clj
#(* %(+ 1 %)(- % 1)(+(* 3 %)2)1/12)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYwxDsIwEAR7XrESsnRHhJCdki9Q8AUTziLInCHYSLzeOKU7yt2Z3Smme1mk1i3tYGiAhWHaw8AyDa0bW3ZsD9ZxpasEBPyhMo44SW6yvIqPyDeB16TfRypvhKJTnpPCX9JHNvRcZs1RQaFdrdPzWiCQ5Q66Droejh0cuf4A)

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. And just a heads up regarding your last entry, `(apply +` is shorter than `(reduce +`.

Comment: Could you edit your permalink to run one of the test cases? As it is, I doesn't help people who don't know Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 21 bytes

```
n->(3*n+2)*(n^3-n)/12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdLCoAwDEXRrTw6ajTFfpzqRkTBSUWQEIoTVx91dM/VvZ3hUKuYYBJmXzrpM3VethKEhpRtV70eLwgztJ1yf3T/OFQvRIwlMTKjMFL8NP6NK9kL)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
LnDƶαO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ8/l2LZzG/3//zc0MAAA)

**Explanation**

```
L         # push range [1 ... input]
 n        # square each
  D       # duplicate
   ƶ      # lift, multiply each by its 1-based index
    α     # element-wise absolute difference
     O    # sum
```

Some other versions at the same byte count:

`L<ān*O`
`Ln.āPO`
`L¦nā*O`

Comment: You can use your bottom program and golf its `ā*` to `ƶ` for a 5-byter: `L¦nƶO`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
x=1:scan();sum(x)^2-sum(x^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8LW0Ko4OTFPQ9O6uDRXo0IzzkgXzIgz0vxvaGDw/z8A)

Comment: `sum(x<-1:scan())^2-sum(x^2)` for -1

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB/Octave, 21 bytes

```
@(x)(x^3-x)*(x/4+1/6)
```

Anonymous function. We could save another 4 bytes if we assume `x` can be given as variable in workspace.
Implements \$n(n−1)(n+1)(3n+2)/12\$

---

One of my approaches was `@(x)-sum([sum(1:x)*i,1:x].^2)`
which is few bytes longer but I found it interesting because It used imaginary unit to change the sign.
I also found out I can generate sum of squares by multiplying normal and transposed vector with `(1:x)*(1:x)'`. Might be useful for future challenges!

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 20 bytes

```
?(:):):_3*(***_12/!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXsNKEwjjjbU0tLS04g2N9BUd/v83NDAAAA)

Straightforward closed-form formula of \$(x-1)x(x+1)(3x+2)/12\$.

```
?      Take input [x]
(:):)  Decrement, dup, increment, dup, increment [x-1 x x+1]
:_3*(  Dup, 3 times, decrement [x-1 x x+1 3x+2]
***    Multiply four values
_12/   Divide by 12
!@     Print it and halt
```

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 21 bytes

```
?
::(";;;!@
{  :
+**}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fnsvKSkPJ2tpa0YGrWkHBiktbS6v2/39DAwMA)

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 22 bytes

```
   ?
:(::
}  "
**+{;!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQUHBnstKw8qKq1ZBQYlLS0u72lrR4f9/QwMDAA)

Two versions using a loop to evaluate \$\sum_{i=1}^{x}{i^2(i-1)}\$. Both versions test the loop exit with `i-1 == 0`, discard the top values `;` as necessary, print the sum and exit.

```
?     Take input [x]; enter loop [sum i] with initial values of sum=0, i=x
::(   Dup, dup, decrement [sum i i i-1]
:}    Dup and move i-1 to aux. store [sum i i i-1 | i-1]
**+   Multiply top three values and add to sum [sum' | i-1]
{     Move i-1 back to the main stack

      Loop exit test can be done anywhere in the last iteration
      (i==1 or i==0), since that iteration does not affect the sum.
```

Answer (score 2):

## ARM (Thumb), 18 bytes

```
.section .text
.global func
.thumb
// int func(int dummy, int x)
// returns sum(i*i*(i-1) for i in 1..x)
// r1 = i (x->1), r2 = i*i*(i-1), r0 = sum
func:
    mov r0, #0       // 2000   int sum = 0;
    mov r2, #0       // 2200   int prod = 0;
.loop:               //        do {
    add r0, r0, r2   // 1880   sum += prod;
    mov r2, r1       // 1c0a   prod = x;
    mul r2, r1       // 434a   prod *= x;
    sub r1, #1       // 3901   x -= 1;
    mul r2, r1       // 434a   prod *= x;
    bne .loop        // d1f9   } while (prod != 0);
    bx lr            // 4770   return sum;
```

A function that takes the input integer via `r1` and returns the value via `r0`.

Uses the iterative formula \$\sum_{i=1}^{x}{i^2(i-1)}\$, iterating backwards. The loop terminates when the value of \$i^2(i-1)\$ is 0.

For the purposes of writing test cases, the C-side function signature takes a dummy value for `r0`.

Test cases written in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int dummy, int x);
int main(void) {
    int dummy;
    int inputs[] = {1, 2, 3, 10, 24, 100};
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        int v = inputs[i];
        printf("input = %d -> ans = %d\n", v, func(dummy, v));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Build, run, objdump commands:

```bash
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main_c.c func_c.S -static -o main_c
qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf ./main_c
arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d main_c | awk -v RS= '/^[[:xdigit:]]+ <(func|.loop)>/'
```

(The objdump + awk trick comes from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31138400).)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ɾ∑²⁰ɾ²∑-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiyb7iiJHCsuKBsMm+wrLiiJEtIiwiIiwiMyJd)

literal solution, squares the sum and subtracts the sum of the squares.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 32 bytes

```factor
[ [1,b] 3 dupn Σ sq -rot v. - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxDoJAFIThnlPMAYQAWukBjI2NsSIU6/LEjfB22X2QqPE03scrrRiaKb5J/qvSYn08nw7H/Ra9klvmFbcUcCfP1C00stG2IbTE5FVnnkqM5bCcE/0TAYGGkVjTwnCeRB7OGxbskuSFAiXWKHKUm3lzvJNYoSpWl3rmZnSM7wdhQOqtYMqQoo69csjiDw)

```
word   | data stack                                     | comment
-------+------------------------------------------------+--------------
       | 10                                             | example input
[1,b]  | { 1 2 ... 10 }                                 |
3      | { 1 2 ... 10 } 3                               |
dupn   | { 1 2 ... 10 } { 1 2 ... 10 } { 1 2 ... 10 }   |
Σ      | { 1 2 ... 10 } { 1 2 ... 10 } 55               | sum
sq     | { 1 2 ... 10 } { 1 2 ... 10 } 3025             | square
-rot   | 3025 { 1 2 ... 10 } { 1 2 ... 10 }             |
v.     | 3025 385                                       | dot product
-      | 2640                                           | output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$9\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 7.408 bytes

```
a
R@-mQJS
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJhXG5SQC1tUUpTIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Port of 05AB1E. Literal solution is 2 chars longer.

```
a
R@-mQJS
-------
a       # Range [1, n]
------- # Use ^ as the input to the next line:
     JS # Prepend the sum to the list
   mQ   # Square each
R@      # Reduce by
  -     # Subtraction
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

Using the [same formula as bigyihsuan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210250/114865):

```julia
~n=(n^3-n)*(3n+2)/12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7PViMvzlg3T1NLwzhP20hT39Dof2lxZl66QkBRZl5JGle0QwGYoaGkalxspaCaGZOnpKNQoaNQV6GpkJZfpFChkJmnEG2oY6RjrGNooGNkAiQNYmP/AwA)

---

Naive approach (34 bytes):

```julia
~n=(a=[1:n...];sum(a)^2-sum(a.^2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7PViPRNtrQKk9PTy/Wurg0VyNRM85IF8zQizPS1PxfWpyZl64QUJSZV5LGFe1QAGZoKKkaF1spqGbG5CnpKFToKNRVaCqk5RcpVChk5ilEG@oY6RjrGBroGJkASYPY2P8A)

Comment: another naive approach almost matching (2 bytes longer) the formula `~n=sum((a=0:n;))^2-a'a`

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 21 bytes

```
=(A1^3-A1)*(A1/4+1/6)
```

This is the heartless Excel version of the formula figured out by others. There is also the 33 byte solution that feels a little more Excel-y:

```
=LET(n,SEQUENCE(A1),SUM(n^3-n^2))
```

... and the 38 byte solution that looks the most like the original formulas in the question:

```
=LET(n,SEQUENCE(A1),SUM(n)^2-SUMSQ(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <strike>11</strike> 8 bytes

```
-ṁ□ḣ¹□Σḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/fhzsZH0xY@3LH40E4gfW4xkPX//39DAwA)

### Explanation

```
-ṁ□ḣ¹□Σḣ
-              Subtract
 ṁ□ḣ¹          The sum of the first n squares
     □         From the square of
      Σḣ       The sum from 1 to n
```

First time code golfing so this solution probably can be improved.

Thanks to Dominic van Essen for the -3 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!  Nice answer in a great language!  One golf you might make is to use ```¹``` to implicitly add the fina ```⁰```` [like this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/fc4kdtEw/tPLLh0bSFQATkNiwz/P//v6EBAA)...

Comment: Also, don't forget ```ḣ```, which can save a bit compared to ```…1```: [try it](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/fhzsZH0xY@3LH40E4gfW4xkPX//39DAwA) or, equivalently [this](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9By3Yc7Gx9NW5gPxOcWP9yx@P///4YGAA)...

Answer (score 1):

## [JAEL](https://github.com/eduardoHoefel/jael), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
#&àĝ&oȦ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0pMzfn/X1nt8IIjc9XyTyz7/9/QAAA)

### Explanation (generated automatically):

```
./jael --explain '#&àĝ&oȦ'
ORIGINAL CODE:  #&àĝ&oȦ

EXPANDING EXPLANATION:
à => `a
ĝ => ^g
Ȧ => .a!

EXPANDED CODE:  #&`a^g&o.a!

COMPLETED CODE: #&`a^g&o.a!,

#          ,            repeat (p1) times:
 &                              push number of iterations of this loop
  `                             push 1
   a                            push p1 + p2
    ^                           push 2
     g                          push p2 ^ p1
      &                         push number of iterations of this loop
       o                        push p1 * p2
        .                       push the value under the tape head
         a                      push p1 + p2
          !                     write p1 to the tapehead
            ␄           print machine state
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

```
{+/⍵×⍵×⍵-1}∘⍳
```

use the formula Sum'w=1..n'(w*w*(w-1)) possible i wrote the same some other wrote + or - as "1⊥⍳×⍳×⍳-1"; test:

```
  g←{+/⍵×⍵×⍵-1}∘⍳
  g 0
0
  g 1
0
  g 2
4
  g 3
22
  g 10
2640
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╡⌠(♠
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b5f42806&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A10%0A24%0A100&a=1&m=2)

For all positive `k` integers up to the input, add `k^2 * (k-1)`.

Answer (score 1):

## QBASIC, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

Going pure-math saves 1 byte!

```
INPUT n
?n^2*(n+1)*(n+1)/4-n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6
```

[Try THAT online!](https://repl.it/@pimsteenbergh/BuoyantYellowCoin)

---

Previous, loop-based answer

```
INPUT n
FOR q=1TO n
a=a+q^2
b=b+q
NEXT
?b^2-a
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@pimsteenbergh/BowedDecisiveDefinitions)

Note that the REPL is a bit more expanded because the interpreter fails otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>73</s> 39 bytes

```powershell
1.."$args"|%{$r+=$_;$s+=$_*$_}
$r*$r-$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrPCoJAEMfx@zzFsIyh5sbutkoQhqfoDTpESAf7A4K1K3RQn33bRYRO8/nxnXf3bYx9Nm3r6I4lDk5uNoxu5mHZGA1k1iXVe7LhpFRPQCYlw8m6CaCKAatYZogokixYBevZ22Cl5iGFX6rQy5/2c5dLIZbsu8ploWUuEkhGjHAAwLN59Q0/dbbHOF7REam@iGuCvPkESk/G@YHhfwSY3A8)

-34 bytes thanks to @mazzy and his genius PowerShell-foo

Comment: nice try. `iex` is a power tool in the Powershell. but it is often longer than the plus operator :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrPCoJAEMfx@zzFsIyh5sbutkoQhqfoDTpESAf7A4K1K3RQn33bRYRO8/nxnXf3bYx9Nm3r6I4lDk5uNoxu5mHZGA1k1iXVe7LhpFRPQCYlw8m6CaCKAatYZogokixYBevZ22Cl5iGFX6rQy5/2c5dLIZbsu8ploWUuEkhGjHAAwLN59Q0/dbbHOF7REam@iGuCvPkESk/G@YHhfwSY3A8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Damn @mazzy ... Thanks for the pro-tip!

Comment: [formula](https://tio.run/##PY7RCoJAEEXf5ysGGcMtld1tlQgE/0SitnoQM9coUL99GzGDeTjn3vsw7eNtO3e3de3pigUOXqVpQKfu5oIxHMjtCqq2fElC1QTk/ARQRoBlpGJElCKeWc9sFt7PrPUiSrLp3Kw7w3rIlJRrzb3OVG5UJgWIEUMcAKmJkeyntefeXvgrqjjrrHvVPduGP6UGMKDoFyb2@Z@L4zoNYPJf "PowerShell – Try It Online") as other solutions in this topic

Answer (score 1):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 21 bytes

```
ɪbwbbbffʍz3ʍf2sf{C}vo
```

Implements \$(n^3-n)(3n+2)/12\$.

Explanation:

```bash
ɪ       (input)
bw      (store n)
bbbffʍz (n^3-n)
3ʍf2s   (3n+2)
f       (multiply)
{C}v    (/12)
o       (print)
```

Testing against examples:

```bash
$ for i in 1 2 3 10 24 100; do echo {$i} | src/interpreter.py 'ɪbwbbbffʍz3ʍf2sf{C}vo'; done
0.0
4.0
22.0
2640.0
85100.0
25164150.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry) `-nii`, 32 bytes

```
{}{{}[<><<>()>]<([])[][]>}[<>()]
```

[Try it online!](https://bubbler-4.github.io/Flurry/#!ewB9AHsAewB9AFsAPAA+ADwAPAA+ACgAKQA+AF0APAAoAFsAXQApAFsAXQBbAF0APgB9AFsAPAA+ACgAKQBdAA==#MQAwAA==##bgBpAGkA#MQAwADAAMAAwAA==)

Iterates through `k=0 .. n-1` using the stack height, adding `k(k+1)^2` each iteration.

#### How it works

```haskell
main = n add-next-term 0

// Initial height is 0
// Increase the height at (push height), so subsequent `height` calls give k+1
add-next-term = \x. x succ <(push height) height height>
= \x. x + k * (k+1) * (k+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [9 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
└V0¯„○aÌ$
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=K3teMy1eMn1cfg==&input=MQoyCjMKMTAKMjQ=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `+{^3-^2}\~`.

Performs \$\large\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(k^3-k^2)}\$ where n is the input

```
          \       Fold with
+                 Addition
  {               After mapping with this block
        _         Implied variable (implicit index of block).
      ^           To the power of
        3         Literal three
    -             Minus
        _
      ^
        2         Literal two
  }               End block
            ~     1-range to
              _   Initialized to STDIN; implied
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 22 bytes

```
f n=(3*n+2)*(n^3-n)/12
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Assembly (MIPS, SPIM)](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spim), <s>142</s> 114 bytes, 6 * <s>12</s> 10 = <s>72</s> 60 assembled bytes

<sup>Saved 2 instructions (12 bytes) from @Bubbler's golf.</sup>

```
main:li$v0,5
syscall
li$a0,0
l:mul$t0,$v0,$v0
sub$v0,$v0,1
mul$t0,$t0,$v0
add$a0,$a0,$t0
bgtz$v0,l
li$v0,1
syscall
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/PzcxM88qJ1OlzEDHlKu4sjg5MSeHC8hPNNAx4Mqxyi3NUSkx0AFJAzFXcWkSlKljyAWTg8hzJaakgHSBcYkBV1J6SRVIHdg0sHqo6f//GxoAAA)

### Explanation

```
main:
    li $v0, 5              # Set syscall value 5
    syscall                # Syscall, v0 = input integer

    li $a0, 0              # a0 = 0

    loop:                  # Main loop (v0 is the counter):
        mul $t0, $v0, $v0  #     t0 = v0 * v0
        sub $v0, $v0, 1    #     v0 = v0 - 1
        mul $t0, $t0, $v0  #     t0 = t0 * v0
        add $a0, $a0, $t0  #     a0 = a0 + t0

        bgtz $v0, loop     #     if v0 > 0, jump to loop

    li $v0, 1              # Syscall value 1
    syscall                # Syscall (Output value of a0 as integer)
```

Comment: Since the square of sum is the sum of cubes, you can optimize it to "iterate `$v0` from `n` to 1, summing the values of `$v0 * $v0 * ($v0 - 1)`". [Like this](https://tio.run/##NY0xDoAgFEP3nsKBkeEzuHAbEAaSj9EAJnp5BIWhSZvXpukIsdZowq45iIvkinSnzTCjZUOSwDoWFplkx01IxQ4rFSb7OYxzffUpE6w/n97zsAvDjw81P2pV9AI).

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks for the golf. (Glad that MIPS is getting popular!)

Comment: You can cut one instruction with `bgtz`, which is the opposite condition of `beqz` here. [TIO](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsAgDEPv/Q6PHuphF/@mzjGEOgbVwfbznW56CCS8JHKmrJopHZ6TudAuILesxAwtE1oE9rmyKWg7bgKpYVjrYLKfA8XYV58KQtjL03sM2/h381/V4Qs)

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
($+\,a)**2-$+(\,a)**2
```

My first self written pip answer!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fQ0U7RidRU0vLSFdFWwPK/P//vxHXfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>59</s> <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```javascript
n=>(a=(x,b)=>x&&x*(b||x)+a(--x,b))(n,1)**2-a(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEADA38iuaZB01b@splHIGhnhwb8bzXFOeqmG@7gezWWLI9nB1gFZaMqjdU2IJsH33nAi0PpfBFYLSmk0AeMIhWvJcc5lhwRmRRwf)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZbCoAgEADA28iuZoT0FaydZbUHhWhkxN7emq85@eUa7@N6bC7L2jZqmTwwCXlRCsIsWiZBw2CtIELuAg2otbP835iALZZcS1r7VHbYwI2I7QM)

Comment: yeah i probably might ditch the reading from input thing lol, i never knew ** existed

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEADA38iuaZB01b@splHIGhnhwb8bzXFOeqmG@7gezWWLI9nB1gFZaMqjdU2IJsH33nAi0PpfBFYLSmk0AeMIhWvJcc5lhwRmRRwf)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 29 bytes

```c
f(n){n=(3*n+2)*(n*n*n-n)/12;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs9Ww1grT9tIU0sjTwsIdfM09Q2NrGv/5yZm5mloVnMVFGXmlaRpKKmmxOQp6aRpGGpqWmMIGmETNMYmaGiAVb8JdrVgxbX/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 15 bytes

```
(+/@:**:@>:)@i.
```

Uses the form \$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}((i+1)^2\cdot i)\$

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxXkNb38FKS8vKwc5K0yFTDyK6S5MrNTkjXyFNzU7BUMFIwVjB0EDByARIGkAULFgAoQE)

```
(+/@:**:@>:)@i.
             i. NB. range 0..n-1
            @   NB. atop f (g x)
(          )    NB. monadic hook, y f (g y)
      *:@>:     NB. increment then square
 +/@:*          NB. multiply square with each i then sum the result
                NB. u@:v where v is dyadic and u is always monadic,
                NB. like atop except u will execute once on the entire result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>15</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
SQ_*D_MS\,a
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJTUV8qRF9NU1xcLGEiLCIiLCIiLCIxMCJd)

#### Explanation

Adapted from one of the formulas in [Engineer Toast's Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253408/16766):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^3-i^2
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2(i-1)
$$

```
SQ_*D_MS\,a
          a  Command-line argument
        \,   Inclusive range from 1
      MS     Map this function to each and sum the results:
SQ_            The argument squared
   *           Times
    D_         The argument decremented
```

---

Original 15-byte solution that implements the description directly:

```
\,:aSQ$+a-$+SQa
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJcXCw6YVNRJCthLSQrU1FhIiwiIiwiIiwiMTAiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ɾ:∑p²ƒ-
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiyb464oiRcMKyxpItIiwiIiwiMVxuMlxuM1xuMTBcbjI0XG4xMDAiXQ==)

A port of Fig which is a port of 05ab1e

### Explained

```
ɾ:∑p²ƒ-
ɾ:∑p     # prepend the sum of the range [1, n] to the range [1, n]
   ²ƒ-  # square everything and reduce by subtraction
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 89 Bytes

```
int x=0,y=0;for(int i=1;i<=Int32.Parse(s[0]);i++){x+=i*i;y+=i;}Console.Write($"{y*y-x}");
```

ungolfed:

```
int x=0,y=0;
for(int i=1;i<=Int32.Parse(s[0]);i++){
x+=i*i;
y+=i;
}
Console.Write($"{y*y-x}");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCoMwFEDRvV8RpIPRKrEd00ydOhQEhw7iENJUHmgCeWkxhHx7aqfLgauwUajyB8HMZAjo9coPapGIpHd2dnKN6KUHRb4WXuQhwZSDd/s9TgRpzGA82QQ7BcH427rybxAdh6u4G385t710qEsc2UQ51DWNWy2gAh728HSzBu2i26cDr8tjEUMVmi0VlOeUcu7YDw)

Comment: You can save 31 bytes if you use a function to read in and return `int`s, as well as make some changes with the `for` loop call. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLasMwEDzHX7FHKU5i53FTFCiFQqG9tIWehSKXhVgqeiQWxt/ublpyKNQ97LDDsDPs6LDUQY8poP2A1xyiaQXokwoB7qAvQlQRNTwkq/do4wIIDtCAHJU89ESgk/Ui06CsReM8E2WJe6lELiXyjmCOwpuYvIU8z8tODKO42Z4dHuFZoWW8L2b3zgZ3Mqt3j9E8oTWsYWvOxd/KZlLZTirretpu98/Vz1kxqyqgIlzbGnocG8guwUXRHh2kYK7cg7tYaukzxaKqfvuRF/Gz8XH15h5t3G7YTX8x6vgdx/k1axjG@gs "C# (Visual C# Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Meerkat Is one allowed to put the Output code in the footer? Then I get to [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoMwFEDR3a94lA6JVknbMc3UqUNBcOggDiFN5YEmkJcWg/jtqcM90zVUGzL5S@hG6BJFO8vCTJoI2uDHoOeVoo5o4OfxDU@NjnUx7Hc/APE1o4uwKHFKe4BKyI8PTFYV3tTDxeulaXUgy6gXA5epUsiXnRJlvntHfrLNK2C07HhYU5nqZTtwWWxbkfNZ/AE)

Comment: Output is supposed to be in the body. With the function call, this is what the `return` essentially does, which is why it's included in the body.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 39 bytes

```
f(n)==reduce(+,[x^3-x^2 for x in 1..n])
```

test:

```
-> [[x,f x]for x in [1,2,3,10]]
     [[1,0],[2,4],[3,22],[10,2640]]
```

Comment: Is there an online interpreter for Axiom?

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 91 bytes

```clj
(fn s[n](let[u #(apply + %)q #(Math/pow % 2)m(range 1(inc n))](-(q(u m))(u(map #(q %)m)))))
```

The naive, literal approach. See below:

```clj
(defn sum-sq-diff [n]
    (let [; Shortcut functions to save bytes
          sum #(apply + %)
          square #(Math/pow % 2)
          nums (range 1 (inc n))

          ss1 (sum (map #(square %) nums))
          ss2 (square (sum nums))]

      (- ss2 ss1)))

(mapv sum-sq-diff [1 2 3 10 24 100])
=> [0.0 4.0 22.0 2640.0 85100.0 2.516415E7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY1BCsIwFAWv8kAK7yOidevKA3iC0kUosa0kv2maIJ4@/tnNYpgpbJ@afWPKq5agYONbcQw6MvgyVJzoUgo/nNHJbvZyZbmm7YsOd4nMTmePnqtOUJGRF@6siCKsjC5ZsVtpbrT@JoIHnnnG4m37Bw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24 bytes

```ruby
->n{(n+n+3*n*=n)*~-n/12}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9cur1ojTztP21grT8s2T1OrTjdP39Co9n@0oY6RjrGOoYGOkQmQNIjVy00sqK6pqClQiK7QSYuuiI2t/Q8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
x=[i+1for i in range(int(input()))]
print(sum(x)**2-sum(i**2for i in x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8I2OlPbMC2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VIzOvBIgLSks0NDU1Y7kKikACxaW5GhWaWlpGuiBWJpAB11Whqfn/v6GBAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>57</s> 41 bytes

```fs
let f x=Seq.sumBy(fun y->y*y*(y-1))[1..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///Pye1RCFNocI2OLVQr7g016lSI600T6FS165Sq1JLo1LXUFMz2lBPryL2f0FRZl5JWp6CkmqmkoJGmoKhgeZ/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
LDOšnÆ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8X/6MK8w23//xsaAAA)

Explanation:

```
           # implicit input (example: 3)
L          # range ([1, 2, 3])
 DOš       # prepend the sum ([6, 1, 2, 3])
    n      # square each ([36, 1, 4, 9])
     Æ     # reduce by subtraction (22)
           # implicit output
```

`Æ` isn't useful often, but this is its time to shine. This beats the naïve `LOnILnO-` by two whole bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 37 bytes

```php
while($i<$argn)$s+=$i++*$i*$i;echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1VDJtVBKL0vM0VYq1bVUytbW1VDKByDo1OSNfpdj6v72dAtd/Qy4jLmMuQwMuIxMgafAvv6AkMz@v@L@uGwA)

Standalone program input number via `STDIN`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
{($_³-$_)*($_/4+⅙)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7v1pDJf7QZl2VeE0tIEvfRPtR60zN2v/WXGn5RQo2hgpGCsYKhgYKRiZA0sBOoZqLszixUkFJJV7BFshLU1CJr1Wy5qr9DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 15 bytes

```
&⑻Ï⑷²⑸⅀⑻:⑨*½²$-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f7dHE3Yf7H03cfmjTo4k7HrU2APlWjyau0Dq099AmFd3//w0NAA)

Calculates the sum of squares then the square of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 70 bytes

```
> 2
> Input
>> L³
>> L²
>> ∑ 1 2 3
>> ∑ 1 2 4
>> 5-6
>> Output 7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsGIy07BM6@gtITLzk7B59BmCLUJRD3qmKhgqGCkYIzMMQFxTHXNQJR/aQlQo4L5//@GBgYA)

### How it works

Implements the formula

$$\sum^n_{i=2}i^3 - \sum^n_{i=2}i^2$$

As Whispers is difficult to deal with when it comes to compound statements inside of `∑`, `Each` etc. statements, it's actually shorter to calculate two sums and take their difference than it is to calculate

$$\sum^n_{i=2}(i^3-i^2)$$

or any other single sum.

This has to be one of the easiest-to-read Whispers programs, aside from very trivial ones. We use the `∑` statement to calculate the two sums, which works by taking the starting bound as the first value, the end bound second and finally the function to sum through last. Both of the `∑` statements have the same bounds - \$2\$ and \$n\$ - so the only thing that differs is the function. For the first `∑` statement, we use the statement `>> L³` (i.e. cube), and `>> L²` (square) for the second. This yields the sums \$\sum^n_{i=2}i^3\$ and \$\sum^n_{i=2}i^2\$. Finally, we take their difference and output it.

## [Whispers v3](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 48 bytes

```
> 2
> Input
>>> L³-L²
>> ∑ 1 2 3
>> Output 4
```

With the introduction of pattern lines (starting with `>>>`) in version 3, compound statements in Whispers are much easier to deal with. Unfortunately, Whispers v3 is currently not available on TIO, so you'll have to use the interpreter in the Github repo.

This version takes advantage of pattern lines to shorten the code by only using one statement in the sum, rather than two separate sums. Other than that, it's fairly clear how it works, given the v2 program.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
LDOnU€nOXs-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx8U/L/RR05o8/4hi3f//AQ)

```
             # (implicit) push STDIN to stack
LD           # push [1, 2, 3, ..., top of stack] twice
  OnU        # store squared sum of all values in top of stack in variable X
     €       # for each in top of stack...
      n      # push top of stack squared
       O     # push sum of all values in top of stack
        Xs-  # push X - top of stack
             # (implicit) output top of stack to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RDḣ²Ø.
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWq4JcHu5YfGjT4Rl6S4qTkouhwgsWGRpAWAA)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 8 bytes

```
RDS²s²S-
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWq4Jcgg9tKj60KVh3SXFScjFUeMEiQwMICwA)

Literal solution.

##### Explanation

```python
RDḣ²Ø.  # Implicit input
R       # Push the range [1..input]
 D      # Duplicate it
  ḣ     # Remove the first item
   ²    # Square each number
    Ø.  # Dot product of the two lists
        # Implicit output
```

```python
RDS²s²S-  # Implicit input
R         # Push the range [1..input]
 D        # Duplicate it
  S²      # Square the sum of the list
    s     # Swap so the range is back on top
     ²S   # Sum the squares of the numbers
       -  # Subtract
          # Implicit output
```